# cakePHP language routing

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

What I'm trying to achieve is that I can change only language prefix in the url, but getting problems...
There is my routes:

```
$lang_regexp = implode('|', Configure::read('Config.languages'));
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'languages', 'action' => 'choose'));
Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/:action/*',
               array(),
               array('lang' => $lang_regexp));


// actual default page; can be any controller
    Router::connect('/:lang/pages/ajax_newsletter', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'ajax_newsletter'));
    Router::connect('/:lang/',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index',  'home'),
    array('lang' => $lang_regexp));
    Router::connect('/:lang/:slug', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'pages'), array('lang' => $lang_regexp));
    Router::connect('/:slug', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'pages'), array('lang' => $lang_regexp));

    Router::connect('/:lang/special_offers', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'offers'));
    Router::connect('/:lang/special_offers/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'offers_city'));
    Router::connect('/:lang/news/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'news_article'));
    Router::connect('/:lang/news', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'news'));
    Router::connect('/:lang/:slug/:id/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'offers'), array('lang' => $lang_regexp));

    Router::connect('/cities/select', array('controller' => 'cities', 'action' => 'select'));
    Router::connect('/cities/select/*', array('controller' => 'cities', 'action' => 'select'));
```

my language switcher:

```
$this->html->link($this->html->image('flag_ru.gif',  array("alt"=>"", "width"=>"14px", "height"=>"12px", "title"=>"")), array("lang" => "rus"), array('escape' => false));
```

`:lang/:slug` is menu entry so if I have menu like `localhost/eng/contact` after language change I get `localhost/rus/pages/pages`... How to change only language prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `$this->request->controller` and `$this->request->action`, as well as `pass` and `named` for passed and named arguments.

```
$this->html->link($this->html->image('flag_ru.gif',  array("alt"=>"", "width"=>"14px", "height"=>"12px", "title"=>"")), array("lang" => "rus", "controller" => $this->request->controller, "action" => $this->request->action), array('escape' => false));
```

Should woork, for instance.

See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

This article: http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/11/28/cakephp-url-based-language-switching-for-i18n-and-l10n-internationalization-and-localization/ deals exactly with this situation of creating one kind of language route as well automatically adding the language to all links.